# Are there any benefits to using lodash/fp 's get method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, lodash, react-apollo

This has been sort of a point of contention between a few people on my team for a while now.

In our application, we're using apollo graphql to make async queries/mutations to our API.

That said, in the past, there have been some determination to use `lodash/fp`'s `get` to set variables like so:

```js
import { graphql } from '@apollo/hoc';
import { get } from 'lodash/fp';

const Component = (props) => {
  const data = get('data.user', 'props');
  
  return (
    <>
      {data.member.name}
      <OtherComponent data={get('data.member.whatever.data', 'props')} />
    </>
  )
}

export default compose(
  graphql(MY_QUERY, {
    options: { variables: { id: 'abc123dorime' } }
  }), // async data
)(Component)
```

And in my experience in inheriting this app, this was error prone. *Sometimes* it would cause an error, and *sometimes* it wouldn't; basically a race condition. My theory is: if react renders faster than it resolves, it would crash the app. The loading state isn't handled nor was there error handling. However I'm not 100% sure on this since I don't really know how `get` works entirely under the hood. The error for this particular example would be that `user` is `undefined` here. ***Sometimes.*** I would usually be fine while we're developing, but our users have reported errors on pages that use `get`. ***Sometimes!!!***

However I've been determined to move away from using `get` to resolve async data. My method is to move to apollo's hooks and actually use the `loading` states it provides to resolve async data **before** rendering:

```js
import { useQuery, useMutation } from '@apollo/react-hooks';

const Component = () => {
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(MY_QUERY, {
    variables: { id: '123abcdorime' },
  });

  const [ myMutation, { loading: mutationLoading } ] = useMutation(MY_MUTATION, {
    variables: { id: '123', input: { name: 'whatever' } },
    onCompleted: () => doSomething(),
    onError: (err) => handleError(err),
  });

  return (
    <>
      {loading && <LoadingCircle />}
      {!loading && (
        <>
          {error && <ErrorHandler error={error} />}
          {!error && <>data.user.member.name</>}
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default Component;
```

That way it can logistically take into consideration the `loading` state and resolve correctly, and render correctly without the use of `get`, and refactoring to this latter pattern tends to solve for the async issues that `get` or `getOr` tends to give us in our production app.

There have been points that `get` from `lodash/fp` provides [null checking](https://codingwithjs.rocks/blog/lodash-fp-usage-retrospective#get-and-getor) which puts coding defensively into practice, but wouldn't the latter also logistically be coding defensively with error handling/loading states?

I guess my biggest questions are:

- When is `get` or `getOr` ever a good use case?
- ... **are** they useful for handling async data?

This is just purely out of curiosity. As mentioned, this has been a huge point of contention between my team and I and most of the issues from our app stems from the usage of `get` and async data. I just want to know if there's anything I'm misunderstanding, or am I / are we misusing `get`/`getOr`.

Answer (score 0):

`get` is not async related at all ... **you should always protect any `data` property/field access** (assigning to other const/variable, passing as prop).

> const data = get('data.user', 'props');

... it's a bit of protection - "normal" `const data = props.data.user;` would fail if `data` not loaded ('famous' react error `"Cannot read property 'XXXXXXX' of undefined"`)

> {data.member.name}

... should be protected, f.e. by `{props.data && data.member.name}`

> <OtherComponent data={get('data.member.whatever.data', 'props')} />

... this **won't fail but instead can result in unexpected `data` value** (`undefined`) passed as prop instead of expected/fetched value.

Without `<Loading/>` it was enough to `if(!props.data) return null;` (before rendering proper content of course)

```
return (
  <>
    {loading && <LoadingCircle />}
    {!loading && (
```

You can simply

```
// '!data' is equal to 'loading' in this case
if(loading || mutationLoading) return <LoadingCircle />
if(error) return <ErrorHandler error={error} />
return (
  <>data.user.member.name</>
)
```